# Date is deprecated. Should I use it or not?

Tags: date, calendar, datepicker, javafx, deprecated

`Date` has many deprecated methods, i.e, `getTime, getMounth`, etc. Should I avoid using it?

Also, what is the difference between: `Date`, `Calendar`and `DataPicker`?

Answer (score 3):

`Date` was deprecated in the JDK v1.1; in other words relatively early during the (ongoing) development of the environment. It was deprecated because of incompatibility with international time standards; while it was intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC) it was found that on machines that use the GMT time standard or those that do not reflect a "leap second" (an extra second once every year or two) that the `Date` class might not be exactly accurate.

For this reason, it is recommended that you use `Calendar.get(...)` instead of `Date`'s respective methods! Also, Java8 has a UI component, [`DatePicker`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html), which use's the new [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class (which is a localized replacement for the deprecated `Date` class).

Comment: Clear! Thank you. So... I should be able to manage all datas with Calendar or DatePicker ?

Comment: @bogALT that is correct! If you are using JDK8 you can just use `DatePicker` and its associated `LocalDate` class; I would not worry about `Calendar` in that case.